# How do I increase the text-area's height automatically so that the columns on the left and right are of same height?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How do I increase the textarea height automatically so that the columns on the left and right are of the same height?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use rows attribute of textarea

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="50">

</textarea>
```

Comment: rows="6" will cause the column on right larger than the one on the left. is there a way for the text area to fill the difference automatically?

Comment: Yes You can set this according to your need can you paste your code snippet here ?

Answer (score 0):

Flex might help:
https://codepen.io/ecopen/pen/gOLgyPj

Note that the `rows` attribute is better at rendering the textarea so that text does not become clipped on multilines.